# Haskell Equation Binary Tree (Mirror)

Tags: haskell

Hello I have an some homework about Haskell.

```
The definition of a binary tree has the form:

data Tree a = Leaf a
             | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
             | null
Enter the implementation of the equal function checking whether the two binary trees are identical.

Tip
equal :: Eq a => Tree a -> Tree a -> Bool
equal Null Null = {- ... -}
equal {- ... -} = a == b
equal (Node a1 left1 right1) {- ... -} = a1 == a2 && {- ... -}
equal _ _ = False
In the above outline of implementation, replace comments {- ... -} into the appropriate code.
```

This is my homework and I have found something but i can not figure out one thing.

```
equal :: Eq a => Tree a -> Tree a -> Bool
equal Null Null = True
equal a (Leaf b) = a == b
equal (Node a1 left1 right1) (Node a2 left2 right2) = a1 == a2 && equal left1 right2 && equal right1 left2
equal _ _ = False
```

This is my code and `equal a (Leaf b) = a == b` this part is not working. I didn't find what should i put there.

Comment: You have used the constructors `Node` and `Null` of the type `Tree`, but there is a third one.

Comment: What you write there depends on what you want. Why asking us?

Comment: @epsilonhalbe, I actually think the hints look very badly structured, going in all sorts of different directions. I personally hint from left to right, which is also how I code. Show the patterns and let the learner figure out what's supposed to happen with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
equal a (Leaf b) = a == b
```

will cause a type mismatch and should be replaced with this:

```
equal (Leaf a) (Leaf b) = a == b
```